# Create-React from truffle: "return this.setState({ storageValue: result.c[0] })"

Tags: truffle, react

In the Create-React box from Truffle, why do we retrieve a uint value from a function call with "result.c[0]" instead of "result"? What's the c[0]?

Answer (score 2):

This strikes me as bad code. When a number is returned from a contract, it's of type `BigNumber` in JavaScript. It can be converted to a string with `.toString()`.

It can also be converted to a number via `.toNumber()`, but be careful about loss of precision. The reason `BigNumber` is used in the first place is because JavaScript can't handle large numbers. It's generally best to keep the number in `BigNumber` or string form (or perhaps hex).

Comment: Thanks! I defined storageValue as a string in the constructor using storageValue: ' ' then I added a function to the chain: .then((result) =>{
return result.toString() right before calling setState. One more question, I'm still not sure what number.c[0] does, can you tell me?

Answer (score 1):

In regard to result.c[0]

`result` is a BigNumber object in this case — rather counterintuitively I suspect you thought you would get back a single uint (who wouldn’t!), but because uint256 is larger than JS can handle the value is wrapped in a BigNumber object, what you’ve accessed (via `result.c`) is the coefficient which returns an array, the first index being the value, and the second index is the exponent.

Credit to rxdizzle for the explanation.